# Node.js: How to serialize/deserialize a React component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, reactjs, deserialization

I would like to serialize a React element (an instance of React component given props) and deserialize it elsewhere. Why you ask? I would like to be able to send the class from one process over stdout and render it in another process. I also want the rendered component to be interactive, so simply using `ReactDOM.renderToString()` will not suffice...

What I've tried:

- Serializing it as a string and using `eval()` to deserialize it
- Using a custom replacer and reviver functions for `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` respectively

`MyReactComponent.toString()` returns:

```
"function MyReactClass() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyReactClass);

    _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(MyReactClass.prototype), 'constructor', this).apply(this, arguments);
}"
```

which doesn't contain any of the methods unique to my component (such as `render()` or `constructor()`).

See this example code in JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/febuzupicu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Not sure what you mean RE renderToString - it would still be interactive once rendered and inited on the client. You don't need to worry about serializing the react component if you have your state in a store (e.g. redux) - you would only need to serialize the store. Of course any state just in the component instance would be lost, but you could write pure components

Comment: The problem is that the React component class does not exist at the destination, so I would not be able to call `ReactDOM.render()` at the destination. I'm trying to figure out how I can access the React component class from the destination, whether that be sending it as a string from the origin (which hasn't worked yet), saving it to a file and requiring that file from the destination (since both processes will be running on the same machine), etc.

Comment: Can you not just send the entire file, load it and use eval on it on the receiving end?

Comment: Can you provide a specific use case? One typically does not share an instance of a component between clients, only the data required to create a new instance elsewhere.

Comment: I'm building an Atom plugin that will allow a developer to write code and visualize the results. I want to allow for ad-hoc visualizations, so visualization code will be written developer-side and rendered plugin-side. All communication is happening console.log -> stdout, so it's strings. I thought it would be nice to serialize the viz code to a string and deserialize (eval) it and use it to render interactive visualizations.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [react-serialize](https://github.com/pravdomil/react-serialize#readme). This package allows you to serialize react components into JSON strings and back.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked around extensively, haven't found anything.

I'm currently writing my own hydrate/dehydrate that converts react components into arrays of arguments to be passed in recursively to `React.createElement()`. I think that's the only way of doing it reliably. I'll probably make a small library for it.

In theory, perhaps one could use `React.renderToString()`, and pass around the string? But then you'd be using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`... :\

Another update:

Here's the library: https://github.com/finetype/react-serialize

It has limitations, and it isn't the prettiest code I've ever written, but it also has decent test coverage. It was quite a bit harder to write than I expected, and in the end I sacrificed some much-desired functionality to just get something consistent. Hopefully those will be improved over time, and pull requests are welcome.

But it works. :)

Edit: After going way down this route (actually added a ton of functionality to that code that I didn't add to the repo because I didn't add sufficient test coverage), we ended up deciding it was a rabbit hole of a problem that should only be used for fairly simple use cases, and that our use case introduced enough complexity that it became too much to be worth the cognitive load it added to the code. I'd caution someone from going down this route.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
// If I stringify this
JSON.stringify({
  type: `React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return <span>{this.props.name}</span>
    }
  })`,
  props: {
    name: 'Jorge'
  }
})

// Then I am able to parse it and deserialize it into a React element
let {type, props} = payload
// In Node
React.createElement(vm.runInNewContext(type, {React}), props)
// Not in Node
React.createElement(eval(type), props)
```

Comment: Generally, one cannot JSON.stringify the output of `React.createClass()`, because of circular references (also lots of ungly hairy internal logic going on in these guys). If it works in this instance, it's either out of date now, or so simple that it doesn't run into problem that any non-trivial example does. It also uses eval, which we'd really like to avoid.