# how to serialize state of react tree?

Tags: reactjs

I want to record the state of the entire react tree to reproduce some status of the app.

The react might be build with react function components with lots of hooks, how to access all the state in the hooks?

Comment: Can you give more context on this? Code example will be helpful.

Comment: Instead of recording the whole tree, can you instead maybe serialize the props in json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: How to serialize/deserialize a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093814/node-js-how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-react-component)

Comment: Sometimes the user might arrive at some state the developers do not expect, and trigger some bugs. It could be easier to debug if we can record the state tree of the app and reproduce what happened to the user.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. However, you may add something like `React Redux` or `MobX` to manage your state globally.